# Does Nginx require an index file for the root directory?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a Rails application, and I'm now making the production environment default. I created the directive

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /web/applications/dashboard/public;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    }
    location @app {
        proxy_set_header host $Host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://dashboard;
    }
}
```

This gives me a `403 Forbidden` error when I attempt to visit the URL of my app. I don't have an `index.html` in the `public` directory.

If I add the directive

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
  gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

and change the `@app` directive to `/`, everything works perfectly.

Do I need an `index.html` defined in the root directory? I would ideally not like this to happen and just go to the application directly.

Edit: Here's a relevant entry from the `error.log`:

```
2013/11/29 07:38:08 [error] 30796#0: *1570 directory index of "/web/applications/dashboard/public/" is forbidden, client: '', server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

The permissions on that folder are:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x  3 joshua joshua 4096 Nov 29 07:15 public
...
```

Comment: Is your app running? Did the _app_ send the 403 error? What Rails web server are you using?

Comment: No the app is running - I can go to other directories like `/users` and it shows up. It's just the root page. I'll update the question with some more info from the error log.

Comment: Sorry, meant the app did not send the 403 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove `$uri/` from `try_files`. Since you aren't going to be serving any `index.html` files directly, there is no need for it to be present, and it is the immediate cause of this error, if not the root cause. Leaving you with:

```
try_files $uri @app;
```

Oh, and make sure you set up a route in `config/routes.rb`...

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks. I thought that you should always have `$uri $uri/` in the directive... What exactly does `$uri/` do that causes this error?

Comment: It causes nginx to try to load the files specified in the `index` directive, or if none exist, to do a directory index.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.